How to make the unit show up at the result after square root calculation using handcalcs and forallpeople Python libraries?
I am using forallpeople Python library within handcalcs Python library. After performing square root calculation, the unit is not showing up at the calculation result:
import handcalcs.render
from math import sqrt, pi
import forallpeople as si
si.environment('structural', top_level=True)

And here is the calculation:
%%render 1 short
A = (78.3*MPa)
B = (56.6*MPa)
C = (80.4*MPa)
D = sqrt(A**2 + B**2 + C**2)

And here is the output:

I wonder whether there is a way of making the unit show up, i.e. D = ... = 125.7 MPa

i use the sqrt() function from numpy this worked perfectly for me.
from numpy import sqrt
from handcalcs.render import render
import forallpeople as si

then just calculate as normal
%%render 
l=5*si.m
b=10*si.m
A= l*b
A_sqrt= sqrt(A)

Output is:
Output

I followed the forallpeople manual where there is Strategy 1 - Manually add the units back on and it worked.
%%render 1 short
A = (78.3*MPa)
B = (56.6*MPa)
C = (80.4*MPa)
D = (sqrt(A**2 + B**2 + C**2)*MPa)

